# How systemd service run on boot until success?

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a systemd service that upgrade linux on boot. Service works but the problem is when debian is booting, **network connection is off,** so service show succeeded but actualy does not update the system.

Other services like Tor, systemd-timesyncd wait until network connection is on.

**How to do the same in my systemd service like tor or systemd-timesyncd.**

```
[Unit]
Description=Upgrade linux system
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target network.target local-fs.target systemd-logind.service
RequiresMountsFor=/var/log /var/run /var/lib /boot


[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c  \
    'apt-get update          && \
     apt-get upgrade -y      && \
     apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
     apt-get autoremove '


Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with asking here, but you may find an answer more quickly in the future by using http://unix.stackexchange.com . You can search there for an answer to this issue, but please don't double-post on both sites.

Comment: Thank you. Superuser what questions are asked here?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic explains that, or you can click on Help at left near the bottom of every page.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, network-online.target is inconsistently implemented and otherwise unreliable. It's best not to rely on it. Instead you can do as your title asks... make a service keep retying till it succeeds. Note that this is something of a hack.

Systemd has a feature where it will cease attempting to restart a service if it fails a certain number of time within a certain time frame. It will do this regardless of the `Restart` setting. The only way to get around this is use a combination of the `StartLimitIntervalSec`, `StartLimitBurst`, and `RestartSec` settings.

[StartLimitIntervalSec & StartLimitBurst](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval):

> Configure unit start rate limiting. Units which are started more than
>   burst times within an interval time interval are not permitted to
>   start any more. Use StartLimitIntervalSec= to configure the checking
>   interval (defaults to DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec= in manager
>   configuration file, set it to 0 to disable any kind of rate limiting).
>   Use StartLimitBurst= to configure how many starts per interval are
>   allowed (defaults to DefaultStartLimitBurst= in manager configuration
>   file). These configuration options are particularly useful in
>   conjunction with the service setting Restart= (see
>   systemd.service(5)); however, they apply to all kinds of starts
>   (including manual), not just those triggered by the Restart= logic.
>   Note that units which are configured for Restart= and which reach the
>   start limit are not attempted to be restarted anymore; however, they
>   may still be restarted manually at a later point, after the interval
>   has passed. From this point on, the restart logic is activated again.
>   Note that systemctl reset-failed will cause the restart rate counter
>   for a service to be flushed, which is useful if the administrator
>   wants to manually start a unit and the start limit interferes with
>   that. Note that this rate-limiting is enforced after any unit
>   condition checks are executed, and hence unit activations with failing
>   conditions do not count towards this rate limit. This setting does not
>   apply to slice, target, device, and scope units, since they are unit
>   types whose activation may either never fail, or may succeed only a
>   single time.
>
> When a unit is unloaded due to the garbage collection logic (see
>   above) its rate limit counters are flushed out too. This means that
>   configuring start rate limiting for a unit that is not referenced
>   continuously has no effect.

[RestartSec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RestartSec=):

> Configures the time to sleep before restarting a service (as configured with Restart=). Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min 20s". Defaults to 100ms.

The idea is to have `RestartSec`*`StartLimitBurst` be more than `StartLimitIntervalSec`. In your case, you would do something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Upgrade linux system
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target network.target local-fs.target systemd-logind.service
RequiresMountsFor=/var/log /var/run /var/lib /boot
# If unit restarts more than 5 times in 140 seconds
#  do not attempt to restart further
StartLimitIntervalSec=140
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c  \
  'apt-get update          && \
   apt-get upgrade -y      && \
   apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
   apt-get autoremove '
Restart=on-failure
# attempt to restart (on-failure) after 30 seconds
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note: If enabled this service would only run on startup one time. To run this service on a schedule look at [systemd timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering. My script always succeeded but actualy IS NOT SUCEDED because network connection is off. I copy pasted your setup but does not work. It says "update.service: Service has Restart= setting other than no, which isn't allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing." Show when reboot my debian, Tor tries constatly to connect until network connection is on for a long time..

Comment: Huh... learn something new every day. Guess you'll have to keep the `ExecStart` line the way you had it and remove the `type=oneshot` line. As for always succeeding... that means `sh` is returning an errorlevel of `0` even when the command it executes fails. Without using `type=oneshot`, there's not much of a way around that.

Comment: I removed type=oneshot and now say "Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing."  why sytemd service show succeded with network connection off? how do I change that.

Comment: As I said, you would have to also set the `ExecStart` line back the way you had it because you cant have more than one `ExecStart` line with other service types.

Comment: Thank you for your time but it doesn't work. I boot debian and my service does not repeat, until network connection is on. I would like the exactly the same thing like other services tha wait the network. Can I do that my friend??

Comment: The problem is that other services _don't_ wait for the network to be up. There's no reliable way to do that. `network-online.target` isn't even activated on most systems. Honestly, running a system update on startup seems like a bad choice, especially when you will often then have to restart for changes to take effect. Why can't this be done with a cron script or systemd timers? Why not use UnattendedUpgrades? https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Comment: Why others service do that? Why "dnscrypt-proxy, Tor, systemd-timesyncd services" and many other WAIT to network connection is on. If I want to run a random script and I want to run when connection is on like other services. Can I do that? Thank you Cliff!

Comment: Finally, your setup is working. The problem is with the command "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade......" . If change this command service is working. Example if I do "curl www.google.com" with internet off service works fine. Is there any trick to work with upgrade commands Cliff??